# Steam pops up with "out of date client" dialogue even though I used the .deb from the Steam website

Tags: package-management, games, steam

Title says it all. Upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 today, (DAY ONE ^_^) and this seems odd.

The exact output:

> Your steam package is out of date. Please get an updated version from your package provider or directly from http://repo.steampowered.com/steam for supported distributions.

Comment: You can simply ignore this window, click into it and press enter, steam will still work fine.

Comment: I still want it to not appear. How would I make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution for this problem, that works for me, [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4321#issuecomment-215679452).

Simply:

- you have to remove **steam-launcher** package using next command in terminal

  sudo apt-get remove steam-launcher
- remove the repo "http://repo.steampowered.com" from Software & Updates
- install **steam** package

  sudo apt-get install steam

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the `libpcre` libraries in the version from Valve website, i fixed the problem by removing those libraries from the steam directory forcing steam to use the one installed on the system.

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.12.1
```

You might have to redo this step after each update steam performs (unless they fix this).

Comment: I think you also need to delete the i386 libpcre.so.3 with `rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3`

Comment: At least for me removing or renaming those two was enough to get rid of the xterm popping up.